# Javascript solution for table-cell on IE6/IE7

Tags: javascript, css

What is the best approach in javascript "vanilla" for solve the problem of table-cell in IE6/IE7?

Comment: IE6? Drop support already. lol You mean display table-cell? Your question lacks content

Comment: What's the `problem of table-cell` and `javascript "vanilla"`

Comment: @Musa To your second question, http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: It's kinda bad start here: a question about an extremely obsolete browser without, well, any real question in it. Improve.

Comment: The best approach is to not support them. IE6 has been obsolete for a long time. Even YouTube hasn't supported it for several years.

IE7 is only used by people who deliberately turn Windows Update off, since IE8 was released as an update so should have been installed automatically on everyone's computers. If people are going to make our lives a misery by disabling updates, why should we waste hours supporting outdated technology?

Basically, if you're going to go this route, then you also have to support early versions of Chrome and Firefox too, which is a LOT harder than you might think!

Answer (score 1):

There's a JavaScript polyfill available that fixes CSS table display in   IE6/7:

http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/

This is a well written script, and really the best solution you're going to find.

I do have to echo the sentiments of the other comments though: IE6/7 are dead, and it's time to move on.